# Is it possible to inject a thread to another process with gdb?

Tags: multithreading, gdb, code-injection

I found a trick to automate gdb commands "less disturbing", to do it I simply switch to the last thread in non-stop mode and stop that thread, then execute the requested commands and continue that thread and then return back to main thread.

But this trick won't work if the inferior only has only one thread. So I need to create a thread that runs forever at the background, by this way I'll be able to attach to it anytime I want without having to disturb the inferior.

The only solution that came to my mind was this:

1-)Break at `syscall`
2-)Allocate some memory with gdb to inject codes
3-)Replace `syscall` with the `jmp` instruction that points to the allocated memory
4-)`pushad` and execute the code that "somehow" creates the thread
5-)Replace the `jmp` with `syscall` back
6-)`popad` and `jmp` back to where `syscall` located

But this is way too hacky and I still have no idea about the "somehow" part. Is there a more elegant way to do this? Maybe gdb has some tools for it and I'm missing it. If not, how can I do the "somehow" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. I found an elegant way to do it, you don't have to do such hacky stuff. You can inject a thread like this:

1-)Write a code that crates a thread in any compilable language
2-)Compile it so a `.so` file(`-g` option should be passed, gdb will need debug symbols)
3-)Load it to the inferior with linux system call dlopen: `call dlopen(".so path",int)`
4-)Call any function you implemented in the .so file you injected by executing `call funcname()`, gdb will pick it up automatically when you press `Tab`(that's why you need debug symbols)